# Char not working in multi dimensional array in C. Need clarification

Tags: c, string

Im trying to create a 2d array for multiple data types but it seems to not be accepting the char data type. Why is this?

```
struct {
union {
    int ival;
    float fval;
    char cval[50];
} val;
} as[120][4];


as[0][1].val.cval = "Testtttt";  ***This does not work***
as[1][1].val.ival = 3;  ***This works***
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are in [c](/questions/tagged/c), thus you should use [string.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/) when it comes to string handling!

---

Change this:

```
as[0][1].val.cval = "Testtttt";
```

to this:

```
strcpy(as[0][1].val.cval, "Testtttt");
```

by using [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/), instead of the assignment operator (this would work in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), not in [c](/questions/tagged/c)).

---

Of course, alternative functions exist, such as [strncpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/)<sup>*</sup> and [memcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/).

Moreover, since C string handling seems new to you, you **must** read about [null terminated strings in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

---

*<sub>Credits to @fukanchik who reminded me that</sub>

Comment: did you mean `strncpy` ?

Comment: No @fukanchik, but that's an option too, I updated my answer, is it better now? :)

Comment: `strcpy` is just no-go because buffer overrun is possible.

Answer (score 3):

In C, this code

```
as[0][1].val.cval
```

can not be assigned to.  Per the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof`
>   operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to
>   initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of `type`"
>   is converted to an expression with type "pointer to `type`" that
>   points to the initial element of the array object and **is not an
>   lvalue**.

Without getting too in-depth into the C Standard, an *lvalue* is something you can assign something to.  Thus, this code

```
as[1][1].val.ival
```

represents an *lvalue* and you can assign `3` to it.

The reason an array can't be assigned to is because it decays to "an expression with type ‘‘pointer to `type`".  In other words, a bare array like

```
as[0][1].val.cval
```

is treated as **the address of the array**.

And the address of the array is **where** it is and is not something that can be assigned to.

Answer (score 2):

Your `val.cval` members are arrays of `char`.  String literals also represent arrays of `char`.  C does not support whole-array assignment, regardless of the type of the array elements.

You can copy the contents of one array to another in various ways. `strcpy()` will do it for null-terminated arrays of `char`.  `memcpy()` and / or `memmove()` will do it more generally, and of course you can always write an element-by-element copy loop.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy the contents of one array to another using the `=` operator; you must use a library function like `strcpy` (for strings) or `memcpy` (for anything else), or you must assign each element individually:

```
as[0][1].val.cval[0] = 'T';
as[0][1].val.cval[1] = 'e';
as[0][1].val.cval[2] = 's';
...
as[0][1].val.cval[7] = 't';
as[0][1].val.cval[8] = 0;
```

Remember that in C, a *string* is a sequence of character values terminated by a 0-valued byte.  Strings (including string literals like `"Testtttt"`) are stored as arrays of `char`, but not all arrays of `char` store a string.

Comment: That's an actual good *different* answer from the first one here, upvoted.